# Difference between conditional operator and && || construct

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Is there any significant difference in following statements:

```
$value && 'YES' || 'NO';
```

and

```
$value ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

Comment: What if `'YES'` was something falsy?

Comment: Nope, just tested it, I'm wrong. Didnt' realize if $value is falsey, the || will still get evaluated.

Comment: They are functionally the same, but IMO the ternary is much more readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're coding with constants, as in your code samples, then no, there's no difference. In particular, it's important that the constant in the position where you've got `"YES"` is such a truthy value. However, when you don't know that what the result values are, then yes they're different. Consider:

```
var x = a ? b : c;
```

In that code, it is definitely the case that if `a` is truthy, `x` will be set to the value of `b`. If not, it'll be set to the value of `c`.

Now, on the other hand:

```
var x = a && b || c;
```

Here, `x` will be set to the value of `b` only if both `a` and that value are  truthy. If `b` is falsey, then evaluation will move on to the other side of the `||`.

Comment: but `YES` *is* truthy

Comment: @Jamiec I'll clarify the opening sentence.

Comment: Ok, now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

They are more-or-less the same, given your current code. If `YES` were replaced by something falsey it would be a different story. The below code compares the two with various inputs.

```js
function test1($value){
  return $value && 'YES' || 'NO';
}

function test2($value){
  return $value ? 'YES' : 'NO';
}

function compare(desc, $value){
   console.log(desc, test1($value), test2($value));
}

compare("true",true);
compare("false",false);


compare("truthy1",1);
compare("truthy2","foo");
compare("undefined");
compare("falsey","")
```